# Titanium Android module upgrade to SDK 6.0.0

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I am trying too recompile my old modules to 6.0.0.GA sdk as its mandatory to make it work on 6 and above sdk. But I am not able to build it as its giving error.
Development environment:

1. Android NDK r13b
2. Titanium SDK 6.0.0.GA
3. Appcelerator studio 4.8.0
4. CLI version 5.0.10
5. Android SDK 23

I am getting this error :

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/krishna/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:347: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/krishna/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:302: exec returned: 2
```

Also when I am trying to create a new module and then build it.

Please let me know where its going wrong. I think its because of some environment problem. Maybe my NDK version is messing up.

I appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out that it was issue of Android NDK version. I tried using NDK r12b and r13c but that was higher version.

Then I tried NDK r11 and it worked like charm. Hope Appcelerator should update their matrix for Android NDK version and SDK mapping.