# getting error while compiling titanium android module

Tags: android, module, android-ndk, titanium, appcelerator

when I am trying to compile android module I am getting this error
`Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:347`

this is my build properties

```
titanium.platform=/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.0.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25
google.apis=/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-23
android.ndk=/Users/Me/Documents/android-ndk-r8
```

and `apache-ant-1.9.7`

I have also tried using `android.ndk=/Users/Me/Documents/android-ndk-r13b`

is there anything that I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm building like this:

```
titanium.platform=/Users/ME/Library/Application
Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.0.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/ME/android-sdk/platforms/android-23
google.apis=/Users/ME/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-23
android.ndk=/Users/ME/android-ndk-r10e
```

You can also try to clean the project before building with `ant clean`

Comment: thanks... it helped me a lot. also we can use NDK r11, so it will be some future proof. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106920/titanium-android-module-upgrade-to-sdk-6-0-0/41180404#41180404

Answer (score 0):

Up til now, Appcelerator Titanium [supports](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-src-29004837_safe-id-VGl0YW5pdW1Db21wYXRpYmlsaXR5TWF0cml4LUFuZHJvaWRTREsvVGFyZ2V0QW5kcm9pZFBsYXRmb3Jt) up to android API target 23.

So you should have used

```
android.platform=/Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23
```